# How would I create a bar to switch between different html files?

Tags: html, css

So, I want to make a sort of tab at the top of the page where the user can go to different tabs, for example, if the user wanted to find out how to contact the company or the restaurant. Does anyone have suggestions on how I should do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way might be using an anchor tag. Imagine you are doing a navbar, what you can do is to wrap each tab with this anchor tag, and refer it to the file you want inside your project.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Since it's a navbar, it is advised to be written inside a nav element as well into a list element, for semantical reasons.

You have to understand how to select the path right. Below, I've posted a couple of examples to help you understand the path. Notice that for home I chose to do it differently which you don't have to. A reason for the home page being inside a folder named home and in a file named index could be to remove the ".html" at the end of the URL. You can ignore that and do it in a file called home.html, for example.

[image: Example: 1]

[image: Example: 2]